# PL/SQL procedure succesfully completed but shows nothing

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I've the following procedure code:

```sql
create or replace 
PROCEDURE Ventas_cliente( p_DNI IN CHAR )
IS

  CURSOR c_pedidos_clientes IS
  SELECT *
  FROM Pedidos_venta
  WHERE DNI_Cliente = p_DNI;

BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test');
  FOR fila IN c_pedidos_clientes LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fila.OID_Pedido_venta||' '||fila.precio);
  END LOOP;
END Ventas_cliente;
```

When I type `EXECUTE Ventas_(88441020);` Oracle returns `PL/SQL procedure succesfully completed`. The great problem is that it'd return 'test'. Why does not Oracle return 'test'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable printing to stdout.

In SQL*Plus the simplest way of doing this is to use [serveroutput](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_eight.htm#sthref954):

```
set serveroutput on
```